# Programatically get supported sub records in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

Is it possible to programatically get all the supported sub record (both sublist sub record and body level sub record) for a specific record type or nlobjrecord?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible because you need to define the record type/sublist type that you need to access.

Comment: Hardcoding based on record type and sublist could be one solution, but I am thinking if there is a better way to achieve this